# Do the tight variable packing rules apply to events too?

Tags: solidity, gas, struct

[Tight variable packing](https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/tight_variable_packing.html) is a known coding pattern in Solidity for saving gas by placing variables that are lower than 256 bits closer to one another in structs.

Does the same logic apply to events?

Will I save gas if instead of defining an event like this:

```
event MyEvent {
    uint256 foo;
    bool bar;
    uint256 baz;
    bool qux;
}
```

I define it like this:

```
event MyEvent {
    uint256 foo;
    uint256 baz;
    bool bar;
    bool qux;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK at least it does not apply to indexed event variables, you are always going to get 4x 256 bit words for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, variable packing only occurs in storage. Since events are not stored in the transaction nor on the blockchain, they're not tightly packed, nor you can save gas by defining the variables in a different order.

See:

https://medium.com/coinmonks/gas-optimization-in-solidity-part-i-variables-9d5775e43dde

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72738646/how-events-in-solidity-are-stored-on-ethereum-blockchain